# Import variable from sub module through __init__.py in django

Tags: python, django

I am going through a problem which i cant import variables from `__init__.py`. I google my problem but i cant find any answer that i can understand.

my module structure is:

```
my_module/
    __init__.py
    sub_module/
        __init__.py
        module_file.py
```

Contents in my files is :

```
# my_module/__init__.py
from sub_module.module_file import show_variable

# sub_module/module_file.py
show_variable = "string needs to display"
```

But when i try to access variable from the **sub_module**

```
from my_module import show_variable
```

it through an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name show_variable
```

Is there any way to access my variable through `__init__.py` file ?
Waiting for your valuable response. Thank you

Comment: u error said that u were trying to import content_variable not show_variable.

Comment: Don't you mean `from module_file import show_variable`?

Comment: I can access a function when i import from `__init__.py`. but i cant access a variable like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work.

This works for me (2.7.6):

```
# my_module/__init__.py
from sub_module.module_file import show_variable

# my_module/sub_module/__init__.py (empty)

# my_module/sub_module/module_file.py
show_variable = 'string needs to display'

# main.py
from my_module import show_variable
print show_variable
```

From the parent directory of my_module:

```
>>> from my_module import show_variable
>>> print show_variable
string needs to display
```

You can also try this for a variation:

```
# my_module/__init__.py
from sub_module import show_variable

# my_module/sub_module/__init__.py
from .module_file import show_variable
```

Maybe something about how you've set up your package under Django. Where is your file that's loading my_module relative to the my_module package?

I've used this before to refactor a single module into a package with multiple files while keeping it a drop in replacement.